# php oop extends problem

Tags: php, oop, methods

i have the following classes.

```
class base {

    private function __construct(){
        //check if foo method exists 
        //$this->foo(); // if it exists
    }

    public static function singleton(){
        if(!isset(self::$singleton)){
            self::$singleton = new base();
        }
        return self::$singleton;
    }
}

class sub extends base{
    public function __construct() {
        parent::singleton();
    }

    public function foo(){

    }
}
```

then init it like so

```
$test = new sub();
```

my problem is that I want to check on `base __construct` if the sub has a `foo` method.
but it doesn't seem to have this method.

can someone tell me where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Why would you want to check for a `foo` method? And your singleton implementation is a bit strange.

Comment: I want to check for foo because it can call a default method if not found. why is the singleton strange?

Comment: Perhaps because your singleton method is instantiating a totally different class called `controller`?

Comment: In your `singleton()` method you do new `controller()`, is this some yet another class or it's `base` or `sub` class? Somehow this part is not really clear what you want to do there?

Comment: oh controller is meant to be the base ... so controller = base my bad :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although you call `parent::singleton()` from `sub` class, but the `singleton()` still creates you instance of `base` class (because you do `new base()`), which does not have your `foo()` method.

In general you shouldn't use/call any methods from base class, which aren't define in it. Because it makes your code not clean: what if you will implement some another class which extends your `base` class, but forgets to implement the `foo()` method? You can end up with fatal errors quite fast...

If you are sure, that this `foo()` method will be always implemented by any child class - you can define in as abstract method in base class - then any child class will be forced to implement it. Or at least as an empty method in the same base class... This way your code will be clean and structured.

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot instantiate abstract class base in ...file.php... on line 28

Answer (score 3):

The method `foo` will not exist as the singleton being creating is an instance of `base`. Here's what's happening:

1. Create an instance of `sub`
2. Constructor of `sub` gets the singleton instance.
3. `singleton()` creates an instance of `base`
4. `base` constructor checks if the `base` class contains a method named foo. It does not.

**Edit**

> i got a url e.g. site.com/sub/foo so the class sub is called and i want the base to check if foo does not exist then i will break the code... foo can be anything as long as it exists as a method on sub class

In this case the singleton pattern is superfluous. Instead, you can start with a basic factory class that implements the desired front controller pattern:

```
class factory {
  static public function go($path) {
    list($type, $action) = explode('/', $path);
    if (class_exists($type) &&   // Does the requested type/class exist?
        is_subclass_of($type, 'factory') &&  // Basic security. Make sure URL requests can't create an instance of *any* PHP class
        method_exists($type, $action))  // Check requested method/action
    {
      $o = new $type;
      $o->$action();
    }
  }
}

class sub extends factory {
  public function foo() {
    echo('To foo or not to foo that is the question.');
  }
}

factory::go('sub/foo');
```

Comment: that makes sense... oop is doing my heading... :) so how would I go about this?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to do, but I'll take a stab at it: you want every subclass of `base` to have a static `singleton()` method that returns a singleton of the subclass type. Is this it?

Comment: i got a url e.g. `site.com/sub/foo` so the class sub is called and i want the base to check if foo does not exist then i will break the code... foo can be anything as long as it exists as a method on sub class